# Distinct results between "emmeans" and "multcomp" - package in multi level model

Tags: multiple-comparisons, multilevel-analysis, lsmeans

I have calculated a multi-level model with a biomarker as dependent variable (which was measured three time), a 5-level factor variable called „module“ as predictor (which is an intervention including a control group) and several other covariates.

The F-Omnibus test of my multi-level model revealed a significant main effect of the factor „modules“. That’s why, I calculated post hocs, i.e. pairwise comparisons for the main effect „module“ with the package "emmeans" as well as with the "multcomp"-package in R. These show surprisingly different results (see code and results below). I already read that multcomp works with z-statistics (and not t-statistics like emmeans) and that p-values and CI-intervals are rather displayed smaller for smaller samples (<30). For larger samples (i.e. 30 persons and more), there should be no difference. In total, I have  300 persons with app. ~40 persons in each group, in the control group 120 (unbalanced study). So, I’d say I have a larger sample and would expect similar results between the two packages. Interestingly, when I look at the results of my MLM model (see below), also using T-statistics, they reveal the same significant effects as the „multcomp“ package. Further, the results oft the „multcomp“ package make also more sense in terms when I look at my raw data (see graph). I have also tried different adjustment methods for p-correction or by using no p-correction at all and the same df-method, but that reveals the same distinct results of the two packages.

Do you know why I get such different results with emmeans and multcomp package? Which one would you take for your final results?

Any help or idea is highly appreciated.

Codes:

```
#multcomp 
summary(glht(M3_ALL, linfct = mcp(module = "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm"))

#emmeans
emm1 = emmeans(M3_ALL, specs = pairwise ~ module)
emm1$contrasts
```

Results:

0 = control group

Other numbers: different interventions

```
#multcomp
Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: lmer(formula = bio ~ bl2peak + peak2rec + module + bl2peak * 
    module + peak2rec * module + +age + hor + 
    (1 | id), data = data_set)

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)    
1 - 0 == 0  0.36031    0.11554   3.119     0.0164 *  
2 - 0 == 0 -0.32786    0.11494  -2.852     0.0260 *  
3 - 0 == 0 -0.07544    0.11623  -0.649     1.0000    
4 - 0 == 0 -0.05128    0.11587  -0.443     1.0000    
2 - 1 == 0 -0.68817    0.13859  -4.966 0.00000685 ***
3 - 1 == 0 -0.43575    0.13983  -3.116     0.0164 *  
4 - 1 == 0 -0.41159    0.13941  -2.952     0.0221 *  
3 - 2 == 0  0.25242    0.13917   1.814     0.2788    
4 - 2 == 0  0.27658    0.13888   1.991     0.2322    
4 - 3 == 0  0.02416    0.14013   0.172     1.0000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- holm method)

# emmeans
 contrast estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 1     -0.1440 0.106 321 -1.359  0.6542 
 0 - 2      0.3169 0.105 323  3.029  0.0221 
 0 - 3      0.2048 0.106 318  1.929  0.3040 
 0 - 4      0.0802 0.105 317  0.760  0.9417 
 1 - 2      0.4609 0.127 323  3.642  0.0029 
 1 - 3      0.3487 0.128 320  2.725  0.0526 
 1 - 4      0.2241 0.127 320  1.761  0.3982 
 2 - 3     -0.1121 0.127 321 -0.885  0.9023 
 2 - 4     -0.2367 0.126 321 -1.877  0.3318 
 3 - 4     -0.1246 0.128 317 -0.977  0.8656 

Results are averaged over the levels of: bl2peak, peak2rec, hor 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates 

# multi level model (R setting default to contr.treatment with 0/controlgroup as reference category):
                     Estimate   Std. Error           df t value           Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        0.57833981   0.07225305 382.75265475   8.004 0.0000000000000145 ***
bl2peak            0.00348362   0.00075672 552.81449219   4.604 0.0000051566462762 ***
peak2rec          -0.00384072   0.00110413 552.93007226  -3.479           0.000544 ***
module1            0.36031070   0.11553583 439.60198129   3.119           0.001937 ** 
module2           -0.32785914   0.11494352 450.22174699  -2.852           0.004540 ** 
module3           -0.07543983   0.11623406 440.63645964  -0.649           0.516655    
module4           -0.05127913   0.11586632 445.20852853  -0.443           0.658291    
age                0.00576536   0.00401484 278.99239058   1.436           0.152120    
hor1               0.06274631   0.10814214 280.72152598   0.580           0.562231    
hor2               0.48812486   0.11532236 280.23372757   4.233 0.0000313271007368 ***
hor3               0.01833652   0.07904604 278.57996999   0.232           0.816730    
bl2peak:module1    0.00318217   0.00144669 551.91605778   2.200           0.028247 *  
bl2peak:module2   -0.00038689   0.00144282 556.55214625  -0.268           0.788685    
bl2peak:module3    0.00121872   0.00145914 551.91030700   0.835           0.403951    
bl2peak:module4    0.00013595   0.00145543 552.78654470   0.093           0.925613    
peak2rec:module1  -0.00501776   0.00213487 554.61415676  -2.350           0.019104 *  
peak2rec:module2  -0.00007187   0.00212124 553.65862032  -0.034           0.972983    
peak2rec:module3  -0.00398714   0.00211343 551.94675681  -1.887           0.059742 .  
peak2rec:module4  -0.00108719   0.00210806 552.82306606  -0.516           0.606251
```

[image: Graph of data]

---

*(converted from answer)*

Thank you very much for your fast and detailed answer! It helped a lot. It was indeed the interaction effect. When I calculated the model without the interaction effect, both packages revealed the same results.

However, this command

```
summary(glht(mod, mcp(module = "Tukey", interaction_average = TRUE)))
```

did not work for me. I got this warning massage.

```
Warning message:
In mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) :
  covariate interactions found -- default contrast might be inappropriate
```

Changing contrasts just worked for the variable "module" of my interactions variables (interactions: bl2peak:module; peak2rec:module). The other ones (bl2peak and peak2rec) are numeric variables but only containing 0 and -70 or 0 and +47 values (I’d like them to stay numeric variables because of model caluculation). For the numeric variables, I couldn’t change the contrast setting and changing contrasts just for module didn’t lead to the disappearance of the warning message.

So I assume the different results of emmeans and multcomp in my case were not only because of the contrast settings but rather also about the numeric variable containing so many 0 values which led probably to the result of the interaction effect being 0 in multcomp package (as you have explained with both contrasts being contr.treatment above).

Comment: Why did you choose to use the Holm adjustment for glht but not for emmeans (where it is also available)? Aside from that, I notice that tge estimates differ somewhat as well, and I speculate that glht is not using equally-weighted averages like emmeans does.

Comment: I am deleting one comment previously made, which I have expanded into an answer.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 9):

I will explain using a somewhat simpler model, but with the same kind of discrepancy. Consider the `pigs` dataset in the **emmeans** package.

```r
require(emmeans)
require(multcomp)

data(pigs)
pigs$pct = factor(pigs$percent)
```

I'll fit an ordinary regression model, making the contrast coding explicit so there is no question about how it is parameterized:

```r
mod = lm(conc ~ source*pct, data = pigs,
         contrasts = list(source = "contr.treatment", pct = "contr.treatment"))
```

Here is the `emmeans` analysis, showing both the estimated marginal means (EMMs) and the comparisons:

```r
(emm = emmeans(mod, "source"))
## NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
##  source emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  fish     30.0 1.52 17     26.8     33.3
##  soy      39.1 1.67 17     35.6     42.6
##  skim     47.3 1.74 17     43.6     50.9
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: pct 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
pairs(emm)
##  contrast    estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
##  fish - soy     -9.06 2.26 17 -4.012  0.0025 
##  fish - skim   -17.24 2.31 17 -7.467  <.0001 
##  soy - skim     -8.18 2.41 17 -3.399  0.0091 
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: pct 
## P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

And here are the comparisons using `glht`:

```r
summary(glht(mod, mcp(source = "Tukey")))
## Warning in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct): covariate interactions found --
## default contrast might be inappropriate
## 
##   Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
## 
## Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
## 
## 
## Fit: lm(formula = conc ~ source * pct, data = pigs, contrasts = list(source = "contr.treatment", 
##     pct = "contr.treatment"))
## 
## Linear Hypotheses:
##                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
## soy - fish == 0    8.8833     4.3051   2.063   0.1272  
## skim - fish == 0   9.6500     4.3051   2.242   0.0923 .
## skim - soy == 0    0.7667     3.8506   0.199   0.9784  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Note that, as in the OP, the `glht` estimates are not the same as the `emmeans` estimates. Here is something to consider:

#### Challenge question 1

The `emmeans` analysis shows that the results of `pairs` comprise pairwise differences of the `emm` estimates. But in the `glht` results, what is being compared? That is, find estimates `g` such that the `glht` estimates are pairwise comparisons of `g`.

I will answer that in a little bit. But first let's consider a different model -- or rather a re-parameterization of the same model using different contrast codings for `pct`:

#### Re-parameterized model

```r
modr = update(mod, contrasts = list(source = "contr.treatment", pct = "contr.poly"))

pairs(emmeans(modr, "source"))
## NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
##  contrast    estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
##  fish - soy     -9.06 2.26 17 -4.012  0.0025 
##  fish - skim   -17.24 2.31 17 -7.467  <.0001 
##  soy - skim     -8.18 2.41 17 -3.399  0.0091 
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: pct 
## P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

Note that these results are identical to the previous ones for `emmeans`

```r
summary(glht(modr, mcp(source = "Tukey")))
## Warning in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct): covariate interactions found --
## default contrast might be inappropriate
## ... (lines omitted) ...
## Linear Hypotheses:
##                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## soy - fish == 0     9.058      2.258   4.012  0.00234 ** 
## skim - fish == 0   17.237      2.308   7.467  < 0.001 ***
## skim - soy == 0     8.179      2.407   3.399  0.00917 ** 
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

These estimates are not the same as the previous `glht` estimates. In fact, they now seem a lot like the `emmeans` estimates.

#### Challenge question 2

What is going on here? In particular, why are the `glht` results different depending on how we parameterize the *other* factor?

#### Answers to challenge questions

To answer these, first note that both packages issue warnings about the presence of interaction(s). These messages are not shown in the OP, but they are pertinent.

The main point is that the `glht` estimates are based *only* on the coefficients involving `source`, without taking into account the interactions.

The answer to challenge question 1 is that `g` comprises the predictions when `pct` is held at its first level. That is because with the contrast coding in `mod`, all the interaction contrasts are zero when `pct` is at its first level.

The answer to challenge question 2 is more complicated, but basically it has to to with making the `pct` contrasts average to zero so that the interactions don't confound the `source` effects.

Finally, note there is an option in `mcp` to average over the interactions:

```r
summary(glht(mod, mcp(source = "Tukey", interaction_average = TRUE)))
## ... (lines omitted) ...
##
## Linear Hypotheses:
##                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## soy - fish == 0     9.058      2.258   4.012  0.00251 ** 
## skim - fish == 0   17.237      2.308   7.467  < 0.001 ***
## skim - soy == 0     8.179      2.407   3.399  0.00894 ** 
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

If you use that option, the discrepancies disappear. I wish they had chosen a different default but I think it is this way to be compatible with old versions of **multcomp**.

My advice is to take warning messages seriously; and, generally, be very cautious in computing marginal means of factors that are involved in interactions. It is usually best to re-fit the model without the interactions. (And when the interaction effects are non-negligible, to not compute marginal means at all.)

<sup>Created on 2020-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>